# updateOne () method taking delay in updating document in database

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I am using updateOne() method to update a document in database. Then just after updating I am logging results to see updated changes in document, changes are not reflecting. But when I am logging results after a sleep for 100 ms, changes are reflected. I am not able to understand why this delay is there. Code is written in c#.

```
private void updateState(List FilesInfo, string state)
{
    foreach(File file in FilesInfo)
    {
        file.State = state;
        file.UpdateTime = DateTimeService.GetDateTime();

        dbrepository.UpdateOne(i=>i.Id.Equals(file.Id), Builders.Update.Set(i=>i.State, state);
    }
}
```

This function is used to update state of the file in database.

Comment: Do you have a cluster or only one instance of mongodb ? If only one instance this not normal behavior and you should post more code here. If this is a cluster look about Write Concern https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/

Answer (score 0):

By default the writeConcern in mongoDB is set to ["majority"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/#mongodb-writeconcern-writeconcern.-majority-)  and [journaling](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/journaling/) is set to true , this mean that if you send write operation to your replicaSet , the operation will be confirmed to your application when  is acknowledged by the majority of members and it is confirmed after is offloaded from memory to the journal file in the PRIMARY storage , for example for replicaSet with 5 members this mean that 3 members need to acknowledge the operation is received successful + PRIMARY need to acknowledge write is journaled  before your application receive confirmation.

MongoDB is very customizable and if you dont need such a level of data durability you may reduce your writeConcern to lower number let say 0(Requests no acknowledgment of the write operation.) and switch journaling to false to speed up writes , but you need to assume that if by some reason your replicaSet change member roles during write operation and writes do not reach some of the members , those writes can be rolled back , but your application will not know about them , also disabling journaling in general is not a good idea since in case of power loss or unexpected server shutdown the mongod process use the journal to recover the lost writes on startup.

For 5x members replicaSet you have following cases:

```
  writeConcern , journaling
  5, true  -> safest write option but slow   
  3(majority),true -> safe with moderate speed 
  0, false -> faster write option ,but unsafe
```

1. On WiredTiger, the default journal commit interval is [100 milliseconds](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.journal.commitIntervalMs). Additionally, a write that includes or implies j:true will cause an immediate sync of the journal so I suggest you play with this parameters to understand the root cause of the issue.

2. Another reason for the delay can be missing index on the "Id" field causing the search to take some more time before the update , check for existing index via: db.collection.getIndexes()